# Detect when a new orphan process is reparented to the current process on Linux

Tags: linux, signals, orphan

On Linux you can set [`PR_SET_CHILD_SUBREAPER`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/prctl.2.html) so that when descendent processes are orphaned they get reparented to the current process.

But other than polling, how do I know when that happens? Is a signal sent?

Comment: Why do you need to know this? Isn't it enough to get the SIGCHLD when the child dies?

Comment: I think the documentation you link to would mention the signal if it were sent. So I suspect the new subreaper is not notified.

Comment: No it is obviously not enough to get SIGCHLD when the child dies because I want to take action when the reparenting happens, not when the child dies, as stated in the question.

Comment: Use some other form of IPC so that the program that sets `PR_SET_CHILD_SUBREAPER` sends a message to the subreaper.

Comment: The program that sets `PR_SET_CHILD_SUBREAPER` *is* the subreaper. Don't worry if you don't know the answer. I wasn't expecting an instant answer - just hoping someone who knows about this stuff will find it via Google one day.

Comment: As I said above, I'm pretty sure there's nothing that does it automatically. The documentation would say so if it did.

Comment: However, now I'm confused -- who do you want to notify? The subreaper (why would it need to notify itself) or the children whose subreaper has been changed?

Comment: I want the subreaper to be notified when one of its descendants is orphaned and reparented to the subreaper. I think you have misread what `PR_SET_CHILD_SUBREAPER` does.